# tap on uitextfield and crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have two `UIViewController` class.(with names:**RootViewController** & **SecondViewController**)

I add SecondViewController in FirstViewController with this code :

```
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:secondView.view];
```

So I create one UITextField in SecondViewController with code:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextField *text1;
@end

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize text1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 300);

    text1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,70,180, 32)];
    text1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    text1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    text1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    text1.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    text1.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:text1];
}
- (IBAction)BackgroundTap:(id)sender {
    [text1 resignFirstResponder];
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [text1 resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Now My Problem Here : when run app and click on my textfield app crashed!!! why???
when app crashed show my this code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

this is my error :

[image]

Comment: Whats the crash message in the debugger ?

Comment: you also might want to go to your breakpoints tab at the top left of xcode and add a new breakpoint for all exceptions, so it might actually show where the crash is happening

Comment: what does mean my friend??

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya my friend I can't choose my textfield you tell me try this [textField resignFirstResponder];???

Comment: Did you get any crash log in the debugger? u should.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Do you implement any other delegate method like textFieldShouldBeginEditing ?

Comment: It'd be great to post how you solved it, other people can have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view controller containment is done incorrectly:

```
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController"
                                                                         bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:secondView]; //Assuming self is view controller
[self.view addSubview:secondView.view];
[secondView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

More info here: http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html